# Recognize extreme weights in inverse probability treatment weighting

Tags: r, propensity-scores, weights, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I have some doubts about how to recognize if there are extreme weights after balancing my population with inverse probability treatment weighting.

For instance, let's look at these results [code at the end of the post] - *I know that age is not perfectly balanced but it doesn't matter as it is just an example*:

[image]
M.0.Adj = Weighted mean-weighted rate for the non-treated population / SD.0.Adj = Standard Deviation in non-treated / M.1.Adj = Weighted mean-weighted rate for the treated population / SD.1.Adj = Standard Deviation in treated / Diff.adj = Standardized Mean Difference / V.Ratio.Adj = The ratio of the variances of the two groups after adjusting

Moreover, these are a density plot with the propensity scores and a histogram with weights I made:
[image]
[image]

This is an example of the balance achieved (I don't know if it is useful in this context):
[image]

What to I have to look at in order to know if there are extreme weights? Do I have to look at the plots? How can I know if I balanced correctly and there are no problems caused by extreme weights so that I don't have to take further action to correct them (e.g. trimming ...)? I don't know how to "recognize" the extreme weights.

For those who prefer to have the code:

```
library(cobalt)
library(WeightIt)
library(dplyr)
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATT", method = "ps")

lalonde <- lalonde %>% mutate(weights = W.out$weights)
lalonde <- lalonde %>% mutate(ps = W.out$ps)

summary(W.out)
bal.tab(W.out, stats = c("m", "v"), thresholds = c(m = .10), disp=c("means", "sds"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(lalonde, aes(x = ps, fill = as.factor(treat))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5, colour = "grey50") +
  geom_rug() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 20, 40)) +
  ggtitle("Distribution of propensity scores")

library(weights)    
wtd.hist(W.out$weights)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with extreme weights is that they yield high variability in the weights which decreases the effective sample size. You don't have to check for extreme weights; you just need to check for an unacceptably low effective sample size. In this case, the ESS for the control group decreased by quite a lot. You might wonder why that is. One answer could be a few extreme weights that dramatically increase the variance of the weights. Looking at the summary of weights and their histograms, it seems this could be the case.

The output of `summary(W.out)` displays the ESS and information on the largest weights. You can see that the largest weights are between 3 and 4, but their values are quite similar. These values do not seem too extreme, though they are clearly quite a bit larger than the average control group weight of ~.44.

You can use `plot(summary(W.out))` to directly plot a histogram of the weights. The output looks like the following:

[image]

It's pretty clear that most control weights are quite small and there are a few weights that are relatively large, which is likely causing the decrease in ESS. There is no individual unit with an extreme weight, but rather a cluster of units with unusually high weights. You can see if trimming (i.e., winsorizing) the weights makes a difference using `trim()`; I find that trimming the weights to anywhere between the 85th and 95th percentile improves the ESS without dramatically worsening balance.

---

I appreciate you wanting to practice your coding skills to generate the plots, but `cobalt` and `WeightIt` provide utilities for making those plots. Instead of using `weights::wtd.hist()`, you can just use `plot(summary(W.out))` as I mentioned above. Also, `hist()` would have sufficed; a histogram of weights is not the same thing as a weighted histogram, which is what `weights::wtd.hist()` displays. You didn't even use the `weights` argument, which is the only way that differs from `hist()`. I'm not sure why your histogram has values greater than 20; are you sure you are using the right code to generate that plot? To plot the distribution of propensity scores, just use `cobalt::bal.plot()`, e.g., `bal.plot(W.out, "prop.score", which = "both")`.

Comment: Thank you so much! "In this case, the ESS for the control group decreased by quite a lot" - Is there a paper or a way to determine if the decrease in the ESS is acceptable or is "too much"? How can I know if the ESS is acceptable?

Comment: You can use your intuition about how much is too much, e.g., going down to 100 from an original sample of 1000 is a huge decrease. You can also do a power analysis to determine how big your sample has to be to detect an effect and make sure your ESS is above that. It's a fundamental trade-off between balance and ESS, though, so there is no single right answer or best value.

Comment: Thank you for your help!